# Impossible to create APK with 64 bits lib under Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, 32bit-64bit, android-ffmpeg

I need to update an existing app on the Play Store. For this reason, since August, Google has requested to provide 64-bit versions as well.

I have included the instructions provided in the build.gradle app as follows:

```
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com..."
    minSdkVersion 24
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 10
    versionName "1.5"
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    ndk {
        abiFilters 'arm64-v8a','x86_64','armeabi-v7a','x86'
    }
}
```

and:

splits {
    abi {
        enable true
        reset()
        include 'arm64-v8a','x86_64','armeabi-v7a','x86'
        universalApk true
    }
}

I am able to generate the APK as expected, but unfortunately both arm64-v8a and x86_64 versions do not contain any 64-bit code.

There is no lib directory when analyzing the APK in Android Studio while the APK armeabi-v7a includes lib / libarm_arch.so.

Note no error message is shown by the compilation process.

Can a dependency cause this problem and why can't Android Studio show an error message?

How can I identify why the 64-bit version is not generated?

I'm using Android Studio for 3.5.

---

After searching about the libarm_arch.so library, I have found that it's linked to FFMPEG. But FFMPEG is not referenced in my Gradle dependencies and I have not still found how to tell to Android Studio to embed the arm68-v8a version of the library as well.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi,
I'm facing the same issue currently, is there any solution for this yet?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I've converted a project of 2 years ago to latest Android Studio, now I need to generate the 64bit, but APK built and Bundle do not generate 64 bit output.

I found out I had a directory which was causing this incompatibility:

app/src/main/jniLibs (this one had /armeabi /armeabi-v7a /x86 subdirs in it)

I fixed it by deleting the directory jniLibs.

Answer (score -2):

> How can I identify why the 64-bit version is not generated?

from  https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit#64-bit-libraries

`In a typical case, an APK or bundle that's built for both 32-bit and 64-bit architectures will have folders for both ABIs, each with a corresponding set of native libraries. If there's no support for 64-bit, you'll likely see a 32-bit ABI folder but *not a 64-bit folder*.`

Edit:
if your read just one the same link 
https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit#port-32-to-64
you will confirm if you are really making any change on your code to be able to port 32 to 64
you could be doing the right step on the gradle , but not in the code.
i can't say anything more if you don't provide a sample
Android Studio don't have anything to complains if you keep your code on 32 and try to build to 64, it just keep your 64 folder build result empty as a point on my first response

I hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your interest about my problem, but ma question is not about how to identify my apk is not 64-bit compliant but rather why Android Studio cannot be able to generate the 64-bit version. See in my description above in which I have added some explanation.